# How to export an Eclipse plugin with dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

So I have begun to edit an existing plugin. As such it has dependencies. I want to take this plugin and put it into another eclipse IDE (not my current one). This eclipse IDE will not have the dependent plugin jars installed. Right now I am using the droppins folder, however this does not reach out and install the dependencies I need. So what is the best way for me to install this plugin into another eclipse IDE? And as a complete package/simple onetime step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with using `/dropins` is that it does not perform dependency resolution to find and include all required dependencies. Instead, you'll want to install via p2 (Eclipse's package installation infrastructure) - in Eclipse  it's what you get when you select *Help* > *Install New Software...*

- Create a **Feature Project** to contain your plugin, include your plugin in the Feature. On the **Dependencies** tab of the Feature editor, use the Compute button to declare the dependencies your plugin requires (or manually add them if you prefer).
- Create an **Update Site Project** for your Feature. Include your Feature, build the site (right-click on the `site.xml` file), and then use *Help* > *Install New Software...* to select the local update site and installing from that.

The Eclipse Help Contents can explain more about all of this, but it's a pretty straightforward process.