# Error: "The import javafx.embed.swt cannot be resolved" on Eclipse plug-in export

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to export a Eclipse plug-in. It is just one Eclipse view I have created from the example over here: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?nav=%2F2_0

While the plugin runs fine, I get the following error on export (as deployable plug-ins and fragments):

```
# 12/15/15 8:58:14 AM CET
# Eclipse Compiler for Java(TM) v20150902-1521, 3.11.1, Copyright IBM Corp         2000, 2015. All rights reserved.
----------
1. ERROR in C:\temp\[...].java (at line 22)
    import javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The import javafx.embed.swt cannot be resolved
```

I have tried to resolve this by adding the javafx.embed.swt to the imported packages in the MANIFEST.MF, but that didn't help. Also I have checked the Plugin Dependencies of the project and the jfxswt.jar is listed there.

In the mean time i was able to export via a feature and update site project, but the error remains. I can open the view, but it doesn't show anything. On closing the view a null pointer exception is shown. Viewing the log this is caused still by the missing java.embed.swt.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2015-12-15 12:25:48.193
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event    [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/UIElement/toBeRendered/SET]     {ChangedElement=org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.PartImpl@1ac3a    6f (elementId: com.[...].View, tags: [View,      categoryTag:[...]Tools Category], contributorURI: null) (widget:      ContributedPartRenderer$2 {}, renderer:       org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer@1dc9aba0,     toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null,     accessibilityPhrase: null) (contributionURI:    bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.   CompatibilityView, object: null, context: PartImpl     (com.[...].View) Context, variables: [], label: [...]Graph, iconURI: platform:/plugin/com.[...]/icons/sample.gif, tooltip: , dirty: false, closeable: true, description: null), Widget=null, AttName=toBeRendered, NewValue=true, EventType=SET, OldValue=false} to handler org.eclipse.e4.core.di.internal.extensions.EventObjectSupplier$DIEventHandler@12e9e909
!STACK 0
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import javafx.embed.swt cannot be resolved
FXCanvas cannot be resolved to a type
FXCanvas cannot be resolved to a type
FXCanvas cannot be resolved to a type
FXCanvas cannot be resolved to a type

at com.[...].View.<init>([...]View.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ViewDescriptor.createView(ViewDescriptor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:101)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:279)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:317)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.subscribeTopicToBeRendered(PartRenderingEngine.java:142)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.di.internal.extensions.EventObjectSupplier$DIEventHandler.handleEvent(EventObjectSupplier.java:83)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setToBeRendered(UIElementImpl.java:303)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:489)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:458)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:724)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:701)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:639)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:634)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1157)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1140)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.openOther(ShowViewHandler.java:102)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.execute(ShowViewHandler.java:75)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowViewMenu$3.run(ShowViewMenu.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: Did you try to export it as described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624603/how-to-export-an-eclipse-plugin-with-dependencies

Comment: That worked, somehow. I have installed the Feature, now Eclipse doesn't start anymore, because of a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Sounds like it didn't work at all?

Comment: I removed my .metadata folder, now Eclipse does start again and the View is there. However, it is empty. Seems it doesn't start the same way as if i start it via the project.

Comment: Are there any exceptions or any other information?

Comment: When I try to close the empty View there is a java.lang.NullPointerException. However this does not happen when i start the View via the UpdateSite project.

Comment: Could you update your question with the new information won and add the complete NullPointerException? Maybe there is some useful information in there e.g. missing dependency

Comment: still looks like your dependencies cannot be resolved: "import javafx.embed.swt cannot be resolved" this can have several reasons but because you seem to have checked that the dependency is packaged i guess it is a classpath issue.. do you have any options there?

Comment: were you able to fix your problem?

Answer (score 3):

For me it helped to add jfxswt.jar to the Runtime classpath.

A related article:
[javafx package javafx.embed.swt not in java8u5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841798/javafx-package-javafx-embed-swt-not-in-java8u5)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Neon, after installing `e(fx)clipse`, I had to add the jar file manually to make it work (experienced this now multiple times, both on Linux (Ubuntu) and OSX).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs
Select the JRE that is used in your project
Choose <kbd>Edit</kbd> then copy the "JRE home path" and click <kbd>Add External JARs...</kbd> the navigate to the path copied (e.g. /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64) then to jre/(if it is an jdk)lib folder and select jfxswt.jar (on OSX /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar).
Then <kbd>Finish</kbd> and <kbd>Apply</kbd>, Eclipse will rebuild your project and add the jar to the "JRE System Library".

This has the advantage that you do not need to modify all your projects.