# Export multiple projects as one Eclipse plugin JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, export

I have a multiple plugin projects :

- 4 for my SDL editor.
- 2 for the model-to-text integration
- and one for creating an Eclipse wizard to my editor.

I can export the projects as plugin jars via Eclipse (Deployable Plugins and Fragments), and everything works when i restart Eclipse to integrate these plugins.

What i want to do is to group all these projects in one jar file, that i can install on other Eclipse machines. Is there a simple way to do it ? (i am not a maven user :/ ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several related and inter-dependent plug-ins, they should be collected under a [Feature](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Ffeature.htm&cp=4_1_1). A Feature is a unit of separately downloadable and installable functionality. You can then create an [Update Site](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fupdate_site.htm&cp=4_1_6) to make installation of that Feature (and its plug-ins) easy.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12625162/639520).

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what i need. I found this step by step tutorial on Vogella's blog : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#exercise-create-a-feature-for-your-plug-in

Comment: i am just wondering if it is possible/efficient to put all needed dependencies along with the feature, so other users will not have to install any additional dependencies from other update sites. For example, my plugin needs org.eclipse.ocl to be installed !

Comment: I think an Update Site project can be configured to include prerequisites. But I think there usual practice is to rely on org.ecliose prerequisites to be pulled from the origin updates site.

Comment: do you mean that i have to add an update site from where dependencies can be downloaded ? if yes, how can i know do it please? i don't see a such field in the feature.xml. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Feature project. In the feature you add all your plugins to the feature contents.

You then use 'Export > Deployable Features' to create an archive or repository containing all the plugin jars.